How to structure my JSON request in my Headless Kirby CMS setup?
I am have been learning web dev for a year and am very new to APIs, but really want to learn. Currently, I am working on a Headless Kirby CMS project and am testing my requests with Insomnia.
I am about 6 hours in to this issue that I just can't seem to find the resources to help me understand. I know I am a little out of my depth here, but if anyone could help me out, I would really appreciate it. I just don't have enough of a grasp on JSON syntax to know where I am going wrong.
Relevant Information:

My Kirby installation uses just one site.yml blueprint file that contains all of my data fields. I am not using pages.
I am using the KQL plugin

Basically, I want to return my events_list field data which includes an image file. I want to specifically return the url, width, and height of the file.
This JSON body:
{ "query": "site.files", "select": [ "url", "width", "height ] }
returns all of my files' urls, widths, and heights, since all of my images are stored in the main content folder (not pages).
and this JSON body:
{ "query": "site.events_list.toStructure", "select": [ "title", "ticket_link", "date", "image" ] }
returns all of my event data, except for the image it simply says "array"
I want my JSON request to return my title, ticket link, date, and image data (url, width, and height). How do I structure my request?
